# OCI: How to bind output parameter of object type

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to call stored procedure (on oracle db 11g) from OCI based client. The procedure contains single OUT parameter of object type.

The problem: I always get "ORA-21525: attribute number or (collection element at index) %s violated its constraints" error.

I would highly appreciate if someone could give me a hint what can be the reason.

Notice: Interestingly, everything works ok in the following cases:

- I replace return type from object type to nested table of such objects.
- I replace return type to some primitive type, e.g. NUMBER
- I make this parameter direction IN and bind it the same way.

Also, I discovered the following things:

- The same error present, no matter if I return the result as OUT parameter from the procedure or if I user RETURN from FUNCTION.
- If I try to call the stored procedure via PLSQL script, everything goes as expected without errors.
- I also tried to create "parallel" C++ struct made of two OCINumber fields and use its object instead of calling OCIObjectNew(), but get the same error.
- I also tried to set `pOutParam = NULL`, and bind it, but then I got "access violation, reading from location 00000".

Here is the code. PLSQL object type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE dl_fake_type AS OBJECT
(
    attr_one NUMBER(12,0),
    attr_two NUMBER(12,0)
);
/
```

Procedure (for brevity I skip procedure declaration)

```
PROCEDURE dl_fake_fun(out_result OUT dl_fake_type)
IS
    l_result dl_fake_type;
BEGIN
    SELECT dl_fake_type(23, 35) INTO l_result FROM DUAL;
    out_result := l_result;
END dl_fake_fun;
```

C++ OCI code (without connection initialization for brevity). Notice: I use MSVS2013 and some C++11 features, like std::string::front() method.

```
// ...

typedef basic_string<OraText, char_traits<OraText>, allocator<OraText> > OraTextString;
typedef basic_ostringstream<OraText, char_traits<OraText>, allocator<OraText> > OraOStringStream;

// Check if ociStatus == OCI_SUCCESS. If not, then print error and assert.
void checkOciStatus(const sword ociStatus, OCIError * errorHandle = NULL);


// ...

const OraTextString DL_FAKE_TYPE = (OraText const *)"DL_FAKE_TYPE";
const OraTextString outParamName = (OraText const *)":out_param";

OraOStringStream query(ios::ate);
query << "BEGIN my_dummy_pkg.dl_fake_fun(" << outParamName << "); END;";
const OraTextString & queryString = query.str();
OCIStmt * statement;
const ub4 executionMode = OCI_DEFAULT;
checkOciStatus(OCIHandleAlloc(envhp, (void **)&statement, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, /* xtramemsz */ 0, /* usrmempp */ NULL), errhp);
checkOciStatus(OCIStmtPrepare(statement, errhp, queryString.c_str(), queryString.length(), OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, executionMode), errhp);

const OraTextString schemaName = (OraText const *)"MY_SCHEMA_NAME";
OCIType * typeDescriptor = NULL;
checkOciStatus(
    OCITypeByName(
        envhp, 
        errhp, 
        svchp, 
        schemaName.c_str(), 
        schemaName.size(), 
        DL_FAKE_TYPE.c_str(), 
        DL_FAKE_TYPE.length(), 
        /* version name */ NULL, 
        /* version name length */ 0, 
        OCI_DURATION_SESSION, 
        OCI_TYPEGET_HEADER, 
        &typeDescriptor
        ), 
    errhp
    );

OCIBind* bindHandle = NULL;
checkOciStatus(OCIBindByName(statement, &bindHandle, errhp, outParamName.c_str(), outParamName.length(), NULL, 0, SQLT_NTY, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, executionMode), errhp);

void * pOutParam = NULL;
checkOciStatus(OCIObjectNew(envhp, errhp, svchp, OCI_TYPECODE_REF, typeDescriptor, NULL, OCI_DURATION_DEFAULT, /* true = value, false = ref */ FALSE, &pOutParam), errhp);

checkOciStatus(OCIBindObject(bindHandle, errhp, typeDescriptor, &pOutParam, NULL, NULL, 0), errhp);

checkOciStatus(OCIStmtExecute(svchp, statement, errhp, 1, 0, NULL, NULL, executionMode), errhp);

cout << "executed." << endl;

// ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After a period of struggling I've found the solution, which worked for me.

There were two points, which are vital for successful binding:

1. Object, which is intended to be bound have to be created by call to `OCIObjectNew()` as it is done in the code provided with the question. Notice: I also considered option to create instance of the struct representing corresponding C++ type directly. But this did not work even if the second condition was met.
2. After the object is created, all of its fields have to be initialized. I.e. fields of type `OCINumber` have to be set to some specific value (e.g. with `OCINumberFromInt()`) and pointers to `OCIString` have to be set to `NULL`.

Another gocha of output object binding (also observed when binding output nested tables) is that the second pointer to object passed to `OCIBindObject` is *second* pointer for reason: it seems, that OCI considers it as array of pointers to output objects. This means, that variable containing first pointer (to which points second pointer) must be valid until `OCIExecuteStatement` is called. This meens, that if you want to extract binding process to separate function, than you have to pass there *second* pointer to the object, which you then pass to the `OCIBindObject()`. Otherwise it will not work.

I hope, that those hints will help someone to avoid hours of frustration and painful struggling through the jungle of OCI (and Oracle DB) documentation.